# Passing float value as json : invalid int error

Tags: android, json

I have an android program in which I take float values from user in the EditText fields as input and send the input values in JSON format to the API.  However, when I click submit button the app crashes. The app works fine with int values but when I use float or decimal values the app crashes.

The Error Line:

```
login.put("NumberOfDays",txtLdays.getText().toString());
```

The error by logcat:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1.2"
```

the code is

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Calendar;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class LeaveApp extends Activity implements OnClickListener

{
     EditText txtDate ,txtLdays, txtLreasons;


     TextView txtDate1,txtEmp, txtBleave;

     ImageButton btnCalendar;
     Button btnSubmit; 
     private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

        private Spinner s1;

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave);

        txtLdays = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLdays);


        txtLreasons = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLreason);
        txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSdate);


        txtDate1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHidden);
        txtBleave= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvL);


        btnCalendar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLeave1);

        s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);


        btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        setCurrentDateOnView();
//      empid();
        addItemsOnSpinner1();

       }


       public void onClick(View v) 

          {                       
            //Calender ImageButton function

                if (v == btnCalendar) {

                    // Process to get Current Date
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    // Launch Date Picker Dialog
                    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    // Display Selected date in textbox
                                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    dpd.show();
                }



                if (v == btnSubmit)
                {

                                     if(isOnline())
                        {

                    if(validate1())
                    {
                        if(balanceLeaves())
                        {



                    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                      String strEmployeeID="";
                      if (extras != null)
                      {

                          String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
//                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          strEmployeeID = value;
                      }
                      JSONObject login = new JSONObject();

                    final String SelectedLeave = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();                       

                try
                {
                login.put("EmployeeId", strEmployeeID); 
                login.put("Date",txtDate1.getText().toString());
                login.put("TypeLeave",SelectedLeave);
                login.put("BalanceLeaves",txtBleave.getText().toString());
                login.put("StartDate",txtDate.getText().toString());
                login.put("NumberOfDays",txtLdays.getText().toString());

                login.put("Reason",txtLreasons.getText().toString());

//          


                JSONObject finaldata = new JSONObject();
                finaldata.put("LeaveRequest", login);
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), finaldata.toString(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 

  }
```

Comment: Do i ahve make some changes in the xml also bcoz none of the answer is workign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

login.put("NumberOfDays",String.value(txtLdays.getText()));

Comment: can you provide the logcat

Comment: it was my mistake. my comparing function was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Integer.parseInt(txtLdays.getText().toString()) or Float.parseFloat() if you want a float value instead Integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by multiplying your input by 10.
1.2 becomes 12. Remember to divide by 10 in the API

Comment: Would you please elaborate this answer?

Comment: 1.2 isn't an int because it is a decimal value. If you multiply is by 10 the result is 12 which is a valid int. Then you can put(String, int). I'm not sure that this is your actual problem though

Comment: what if the value is 1.9?  1.9 and 19 has huge difference. Do you really think that this smart idea?

Comment: The difference isn't a problem if you are able to divide the number by 10 in the API. You get the original float value back. But you have to be in control of the API

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 52.92;
login.put("NumberOfDays", f);
```

Seems working.